# Dynamic setup of the Y-Labels (positions) in matplotlib rectangle plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, rectangles, axis-labels, yaxis

I am using matplotlib.patches.rectangle package to plot multiple rectangles. And in the Y-axis I am trying to name those rectangles. The number of rectangles is not fixed, so the position of the label has to be dynamic according to the number of the rectangles.

Below I have attached the images for various scenarios: 1 rect or 2 rect or 3 rect and so on.. Currently, I have manually set up the Y-Labels with manual spaces between the texts but is there any way to automate so that the text appears in the center of the rectangle depending on the number of rectangles.

I am using manual spaces for different conditions for 3 different cases but in reality, the cases will not be limited to 3, so need something more dynamic.

My code (for 2-rect): `ax.set_ylabel('LAYER-1                     LAYER-2', color='g')`

My code (for 3-rect): `ax.set_ylabel('LAYER-1           LAYER-2          LAYER-3', color='g')`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways to do it, but I used `ax.text(x,y,text)` to set it up. The x-value can be negative. The text position is adjusted manually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i in range(4):
    y_pos = 5+(i*20)
    r = patches.Rectangle(xy=(2, y_pos), width=96, height=10, color='r', fill=False)
    ax.text(-22, y_pos+2, 'Layer-{}'.format(i), color='g')
    ax.add_patch(r)

ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
```

[image]